# GNU make multiple extensions

Tags: makefile, substitution

I have multiple target being produced that differ only by the extension. I would like to be able to address all files in this collection as a single unit in both target and dependency specifications. In other words, given a string and a list of suffixes i want a list of `srting.suffix`s

Do I need a new function (`call`-`eval`)? Or can this be resolved with existing text functions?

Thus, I have:

```
t.ex1 t.ex2 t.ex3 ...: data
    generate --from data

next: t.ex1 t.ex2 t.ex3 ...
    generate --from t.ex1 t.ex2 t.ex3 ...
```

And I want:

```
extensions = ".ex1 .ex2 .ex3 ..."

subs(t,$(extensions)): data
    generate --from data

next: subs(t,$(extensions))
    generate --from subs(t,$(extensions))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it looks like the `addprefix` builtin string function will do it for you:

```
extensions = .ex1 .ex2 .ex3 ...

$(addprefix t,$(extensions)): data
    generate --from data

next: $(addprefix t,$(extensions))
    generate --from $(addprefix t,$(extensions))
```

Or, more simplified:

```
extensions := .ex1 .ex2 .ex3 ...

files := $(addprefix t,$(extensions))

$(files): data
    generate --from data

next: $(files)
    generate --from $(files)
```